# Why do these two variables return different results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".chat-b").each(function(){ 
    other_user = $(this).attr("ref");

var check_for_new = (
    typeof asynco_dt === "object" 
    && asynco_dt.new_messages > 0) ? {
            "action":"chat_with_user","user":other_user,"new_only":true
        }:{
            "action":"chat_with_user","user":other_user
        };
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo $main_dir; ?>core/simcheck.php",
        data:check_for_new,
        success:function(chat_sync){
             if(typeof messages_p === "string") {delete messages_p;}  //cringe. yep lol    
             num = chat_sync.messages.length - 1;
             x = chat_sync.messages[num].postid;   //get the postid of the very last post in a chat comment chain    
             y = (typeof $(".chat-b[ref='"+ check_for_new.user +"'] .spacer .chat_box p:last").attr("num") !== "string") ? 0 : $(".chat-b[ref='"+check_for_new.user+"'] .spacer .chat_box p:last").attr("num"); //just a quick fix for those pre-loaded chat boxes        
   if(typeof chat_sync.messages === "object" && x > y){ //inserting the chat box in}
```

What is the explanation as to why `other_user` the variable has a different returned result when inside the `$.ajax` function scope as opposed to `check_for_new.user` even though they are based on the same variable? I initially thought it was about function scope

There's probably more code needed to be posted for the context needed to answer this question, which I will freely post

Comment: `other_user` isn't local to the function so it gets overwritten by the other iterations of `.each` before any of the `.ajax` calls get a chance to run.

Comment: ah so it is sort of  about scope.

Comment: @HansMarcon u should not use ajax call inside a loop. If u want to create chat app using ajax, u may find ajax long polling useful.

Comment: That is only for the initial loading of the chat data, so it's actually not taxing on resources at all. But what's long polling?